# How to make this piece of code more efficient (KS Test)

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pyspark, kolmogorov-smirnov

My data look like these

```
id1,id2,similarity
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL1,1
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL1,0.18
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL1,0.56
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL1,0.64
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL1,0.12
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL2,0.18
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL2,1
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL2,0.26
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL2,0.78
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL2,0.33
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL3,0.56
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL3,0.26
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL3,1
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL3,0.04
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL3,0.85
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL4,0.64
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL4,0.78
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL4,0.04
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL4,1
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL4,0.49
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL5,12
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL5,0.33
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL5,0.85
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL5,0.49
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL5,1
```

The whole file is around 197million lines (10GB). My goal is to compare the distributions of column 3 for each compound in column 1. With a lot of refactoring I managed to have this piece of code

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
import re

with open('example.csv', 'r') as f, open('Metrics.tsv', 'a') as f_out:
    f_out.write('compound_1' + '\t' + 'compound_2' + '\t' + 'Similarity' + '\t' + 'KS Distance' + '\n')
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter = ',', lineterminator = '\n', header = None)
    d = {}
    l_id1 = []
    l_id2 = []
    l_sim = []
    uniq_comps = df.iloc[:, 0].unique().tolist()
    for i in uniq_comps:
        d[i] = []
    for j in range(df.shape[0]):
        d[df.iloc[j, 0]].append(df.iloc[j, 2])
        l_id1.append(df.iloc[j, 0])
        l_id2.append(df.iloc[j, 1])
        l_sim.append(df.iloc[j, 2])
    for k in range(len(l_id1)):
        sim = round(l_sim[k]*100, 0)/100
        ks = re.findall(r"statistic=(.*)\,.*$", str(ks_2samp(d[l_id1[k]], d[l_id2[k]])))
        f_out.write(l_id1[k] + '\t' + l_id2[k] + '\t' + str(sim) + '\t' + str(''.join(ks)) + '\n')
```

which runs but as expected is extremely slow. Does anyone have any ideas of how it could be made faster? My desired output looks like this

```
 compound_1,compound_2,Similarity,KS Distance
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL1,1.0,0.0
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL1,0.18,0.4
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL1,0.56,0.2
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL1,0.64,0.2
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL1,0.12,0.4
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL2,0.18,0.4
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL2,1.0,0.0
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL2,0.26,0.2
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL2,0.78,0.4
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL2,0.33,0.2
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL3,0.56,0.2
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL3,0.26,0.2
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL3,1.0,0.0
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL3,0.04,0.2
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL3,0.85,0.2
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL4,0.64,0.2
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL4,0.78,0.4
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL4,0.04,0.2
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL4,1.0,0.0
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL4,0.49,0.2
CHEMBL1,CHEMBL5,12.0,0.4
CHEMBL2,CHEMBL5,0.33,0.2
CHEMBL3,CHEMBL5,0.85,0.2
CHEMBL4,CHEMBL5,0.49,0.2
CHEMBL5,CHEMBL5,1.0,0.0
```

Would it be wiser to run it in Pyspark due to the size of the data? If so, how could a similar effect be achieved?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should rather be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you post few lines of each file to see the format. To reduce the amount of data, one option would be generate histogram or ECDF to limit de size in memory.

Comment: @jlandercy Are my image files of the data not visible?

Comment: Well image of data are very poor way to communicate data.You should copy paste reusable code to make your question match the SO standard. You can also read [mcve] to get more insight about it. And yes it is in interesting to have the structure of your files because you are running regular expression on it.

Comment: @jlandercy Noted. I edited my question content.

Comment: I was busy until now, I am looking to your code and I wonder if you could explain in English what test you are performing. It seems you collect data based on `Id1` and then you want to compare distributions based on the second Id2, but the last loop does not iterate through the complete list. Anyway I have few remarks to improve performance, I will add it once I get the correct test you want to perform.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski While this may be on-topic on CR, in the future, please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *needs focus* (as I am doing here), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Answer (score 0):

### Code check

There are some key points that should be highlighted and may improve the performance:

- You already have all the data loaded in RAM as you opened the CSV in pandas, then it is not necessary to have copy of that data into lists (eg. `l_id1`, `l_id2`, etc.). Avoid whenever possible having multiple copies of data, it undermines performance and makes code harder to debug.
- When dealing with Pandas DataFrame, try to avoid writing explicit loops as often as possible, there should have a method that does it for you, such as `groupby`.
- Scipy statistic package returns a Result object which always exposes `statistic` and `pvalue` member, use it instead of casting into string and then extract value using regular expression.
- Avoid unnecessary call to expensive function, in the last loop you compute a lot of time the same quantity for the Two Sample KS Test, instead compute each once and merge results with dataset afterward.

### Refactoring

As you seems to be able to open the CSV using pandas, I will assume the complete file fit in your memory. Checking twice, numerical data should fit in 2Gb of RAM.

```
8 bytes*197e6 rows/1024**3 ~ 1.47 Gb
```

It is not clear what you want to compute. I will assume you want to collect data based on the `id1` column, then you want to check if distribution are equivalent using the Two Sample Kolmogorov-Smirnow test based on each possible pair of identifiers. If this is not what you want to do, please update your post to detail what you intend to compute.

Let's create a trial DataFrame:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats

N = 10**6
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id1": np.random.choice([f"CHEMBL{i:d}" for i in np.arange(1, 6)], N),
    "id2": np.random.choice([f"CHEMBL{i:d}" for i in np.arange(1, 6)], N),
    "value": np.random.uniform(0, 12, N)
})
```

The trial dataset looks like:

```
       id1      id2      value
0  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL3  10.719870
1  CHEMBL2  CHEMBL5   2.911339
2  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL4   0.001595
3  CHEMBL2  CHEMBL3   0.148120
4  CHEMBL5  CHEMBL2   4.683689
```

Once the DataFrame is created, it is easy to group data by identifier using [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) method. Then we can apply a statistical test on all possible pairs of identifier. If we assemble everything in a generator, it is about:

```
def apply_test(df, idkey="id", valuekey="value", test=stats.ks_2samp):
    """
    Apply statistical test to each possible pair of identifier
    """
    # Group by identifier:
    g = df.groupby(idkey)
    # Generate all 2-combination of identifier:
    for k1, k2 in itertools.combinations(g.groups.keys(), 2):
        # Apply Statistical Test to grouped data:
        t = test(df.loc[g.groups[k1],valuekey], df.loc[g.groups[k2],valuekey])
        # Store Identifier pair:
        res = {"id1": k1, "id2": k2}
        # Store statistics and p-value:
        res.update({k: getattr(t, k) for k in t._fields})
        # Yield result:
        yield res
```

At this point, just apply the function on the dataframe:

```
r = pd.DataFrame([x for x in apply_test(df)])
```

It returns for the trial dataset:

```
       id1      id2  statistic    pvalue
0  CHEMBL1  CHEMBL2   0.002312  0.657859
1  CHEMBL1  CHEMBL3   0.002125  0.756018
2  CHEMBL1  CHEMBL4   0.001701  0.934290
3  CHEMBL1  CHEMBL5   0.002560  0.527594
4  CHEMBL2  CHEMBL3   0.002155  0.741524
5  CHEMBL2  CHEMBL4   0.001766  0.914602
6  CHEMBL2  CHEMBL5   0.003035  0.315677
7  CHEMBL3  CHEMBL4   0.001668  0.944053
8  CHEMBL3  CHEMBL5   0.002603  0.507482
9  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL5   0.002661  0.479805
```

Then we can merge those results with the original dataframe:

```
df.merge(r)

            id1      id2      value  statistic    pvalue
0       CHEMBL2  CHEMBL5   2.911339   0.003035  0.315677
1       CHEMBL2  CHEMBL5   6.583948   0.003035  0.315677
2       CHEMBL2  CHEMBL5  10.237092   0.003035  0.315677
3       CHEMBL2  CHEMBL5   8.049175   0.003035  0.315677
4       CHEMBL2  CHEMBL5   3.977925   0.003035  0.315677
...         ...      ...        ...        ...       ...
400776  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL5   4.339528   0.002661  0.479805
400777  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL5   5.353133   0.002661  0.479805
400778  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL5  10.599985   0.002661  0.479805
400779  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL5   9.701375   0.002661  0.479805
400780  CHEMBL4  CHEMBL5   7.951454   0.002661  0.479805
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Yes, you understood me correctly. I want to compare the similarity distributions for each pair, and compare them to that pair's similarity value. For that reason, having the similarity value in the output file would be preferred. Where in your function should I add this? Before updating the res?

Comment: Just change to `valuekey="similarity"`. But in the result you will not have both similarity and statistic as KS test takes two series (you will not compute it on two single values), that what it is unclear to me in your expected output.

Comment: I want to calculate the KS statistic for each combination, just as you showed above, and then use the distribution of those statistics (Density vs Similarity value) for each similarity level (0.1 - 0.9). For example, I would like to see the distribution of the KS statistics of all the combinations with 0.30<=Similarity<=0.39. Thats why I need the initial similarity of the pairs included.

Comment: I am sorry I do my best but I do not understand what you want to compute. Please update your post (not in comment) with a procedure (eg. bullet list) and a complete example of computation (sten by step). Make it small but complete and understandable.